# what is the Jacobian of this function?

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, machine-learning

$f(x)=xx^{T}$ for  $x\in{\Bbb{R}^{n}}$

[my solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iRYn.jpg)

[the rest of my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns3tE.jpg)

Comment: $(\mathrm D f)_{ij}=\partial_j f_i$

Comment: more in detail ? could you give me the solution for my task ? i need a example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize you are asking about differentiation of matrix with respect to a vector.

The answer I had given was classical differentiation (see below). I keep it because I think you have first to understand this notion before considering the more complex differentiation with respect to a vector.

The easiest way to apprehend a jacobian is to consider its action on an "infinitesimal element".

Let $H$ be a vector (think to it as a small increment).

Write :

$$f(X+H)=(X+H)(X+H)^T=(X+H)(X^T+H^T)$$

$$f(X+H)=\underbrace{XX^T}_{f(X)}+\underbrace{XH^T+HX^T}_{J_X(f)(H)}+HH^T$$

in which we have recognized a Taylor expansion.

For example, in the 2D case, with notations $X=\binom{x}{y}$ and $H=\binom{h}{k}$:

$$J_X(f)(H)=XH^T+HX^T=\binom{x}{y}(h \ \ k)+\binom{h}{k}(x \ \ y)=\begin{pmatrix}2xh&xk+yh\\xk+yh&2yk\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

Said with a sentence: the jacobian $J_X$ of $f$ in point $X$ acts on differential element $H$. Do not isolate it from this differential element.

Remark: (1) is an **exact** Taylor expansion with  second order term:

$$HH^T=\begin{pmatrix}h^2&hk\\ hk&k^2\end{pmatrix}$$
(with second order entries, which is quite normal).

Comment: na too difficult,  i want to explain it in my way. but still thanks

Comment: Sorry but it is absolutely standard: see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3099454). All new things are difficult ; working on them makes them less and less difficult, believe me.

Comment: in my lecture this is not known, i thonk icannot use it,

Comment: This is different. May I ask you what is your domain and level of studies ?

Comment: i read the book mathmatics fo rmachine learning, https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf    , exercies 5, 5.5 , i do not have any  clue

Comment: I have had a look at your book : it is the differentiation of a matrix with respect to a vector which is a different notion.

Comment: could you show me the solution for my task with trespect to this notion in the book, please

Comment: 1) Yes it is a tensor : It is an application of their formula (5.93) with $M=n$ and $N=1$ that they consider as "difficult". I will not enter into the details 2) The way they manage their derivative as a tensor with complicated indices management is not satisfying for me: there is another presentation using the so-called "Kronecker product" which is preferable. 3) I end with a general comment. As I am a teacher, I am almost certain that if you consider my answer as difficult (although it is very straightforward) it means that you should first master the **basics** in analysis [to be continued]

Comment: [Ctd] like Taylor expansion before undertaking much more complicated things involving for example tensors, in particular with this book.

Comment: you mean the example of 5.13 they refer to ?

Comment: Yes, the "jungle" you find there...

Comment: ah there is also an example, i can transform a matrix into a vctor then compute the gradient and reshape it to a tensor

Comment: i post my solutios, would be nice if you can check up, on page 155 in this book there is an example

Comment: I have had a look at your solution. Honestly, as I am not certain of my own computations using Kronecker product, I will refrain to say "es ist richtig". Besides, have a look at this nicely written document : https://www.janmagnus.nl/misc/mdc-ch18.pdf part of a book "Matrix Differential calculus with applications in Statistics and Econometrics".

Comment: danke dennoch , ich frage das mal in einem anderem forum, anscheinend ist dieses Mathe sehr abstrakt. also ich könnte deinen Lösungsvorschlag locker verstehen aber es bringt nichts wenn ich das nicht auf die methode mache, die im buch vorgeschlagen wurde, weil ich denke es hat einen grund wieso der Auto ausgerchnet es so will.

Comment: Ich verstehe... These questions of derivation with respect to vector or matrices are thorny. And I have understood in this practical application that I hadn't a sufficient understanding of them... But this will trigger me to work for a better understanding. So, danke...

Answer (score 0):

Let
$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T$
be a $N\times N$ matrix.
The $(i,j)$-th element is
$$
A_{ij}
= x_i x_j
= 
\mathbf{e}_i^T \mathbf{x}:
\mathbf{e}_j^T \mathbf{x}
$$
Here the colon operator denotes the
Frobenius inner product.

The differential
gives
$$
dA_{ij} = 
\mathbf{E}_{ij}\mathbf{x}:
d\mathbf{x}
$$
with the symmetric matrix
$\mathbf{E}_{ij}=
\mathbf{e}_i \mathbf{e}_j^T+
\mathbf{e}_j \mathbf{e}_i^T$.

We deduce the derivative term
$$
\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial x_k}
=
\mathbf{e}_k^T \mathbf{E}_{ij}\mathbf{x}
$$
which is indeed a
$N\times N \times N$ third-order tensor
as explained by Jean-Marie.